# Reduce executable file size

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, filesize

The project that I am working on has seen the exe file grow from 600 KB to 21MB. I can't figure out based on the additions that have been made what would account for the jump in the exe size. The project was originally built in VS 2013 and now I'm using VS 2017. Are there additional default options that can be disabled to make the build smaller?

Comment: Identical code between the VS2013 and VS2017 builds?

Comment: Did you add any huge pictures or other resources? You could open your executable ildasm, open the MANIFEST node and have a look which part is biggest.

Comment: is this release or debug builds?

Comment: I use a few things from C# 6 so I'm not able to build the solution using 2013 anymore to test. I added a new .ico file but it doesn't account for the leap in size. Both the debug and release builds are larger.